# Is it on the Stack or Heap?

Tags: c, heap-memory, stack-memory

I have some C code that is something of a puzzle. For a reason to do with this code, I'm wondering how I can tell if a `struct` object **is ending up on the heap or stack?**

The objects are **not** being created with `malloc` or `calloc`. They start their life in the form of an array. For the purposes of this post, I'm going to call the struct Emp.

```
Emp myEmp[6];

/* Each myEmp[?] item is populated in code */
```

The objects are sorted and manipulated in various ways and at some point, the objects are copied and then handed to a array-pointer. The copy is done via `memcpy`. The objects are then put in to something like: `Emp* emps_a[6]`.

The objects go from a copy and are assigned in to the above emps_a.

```
int i;
for( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
{
    emps_a[i] = myEmpsCopy + i;
}
```

I'm not sure if some or any of this has bearing on my question. I never need free() or do memory clean up... I'm afraid I don't know too much about C.

The help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Rule of thumb: if you called malloc, you must call free. The inverse--If you didn't call malloc, you mustn't call free--is usually, but not always, true. (Some functions will call malloc for you. If they do, this should be spelled out in big red letters in the function's documentation.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Leaving global variables and variables declared with `static` modifier (which are allocated in a separate memory region) aside, local variables declared in a function body are allocated on the stack whereas whatever you call `malloc` for is allocated on the heap. Also, C99 variable sized arrays and memory allocated with `_alloca` will end up on stack.

```
int* x[10];   // The addresses are held on the stack
int i;        // On the stack
for(i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
   x[i] = malloc(sizeof(int)*10);  // Allocates memory on the heap
```

For example, in the above code, there's an array of `int*` values on the stack holding addresses to 10 different locations in the heap.

Comment: ...and "static" variables are probably in their own region of memory.

Comment: Yeah, along with globally declared things.

Comment: So your saying in my example above, everything ends up on the stack. It isn't possible for anything to end up on the heap?

Comment: C is very explicit. If you don't malloc() it, it's not on the heap.

Comment: Indeed. In C, that's the whole thing. C++ might run constructors that can end up putting some stuff on heap too.

Comment: "Whatever you're declaring statically in a function body is allocated on stack" -- garbage and needed editing before it deserved to be accepted. Whatever you're declaring NON-STATICALLY in a function body is allocated on stack...

Comment: @Windows programmer: "statically declaring" doesn't mean declaring with the "static" modifier. I mean to say, the declaration is "static" at compile time, as opposed to "dynamic allocation."

Comment: Can you overflow the stack if the array is too large then?