# Is it possible to get StackOverflowError without recursion?

Tags: java, stack-overflow

I have a task to get "StackOverflowError" in java without using -Xss and recursion. I really don't have ideas... Only some nonsense like generating huge java class at runtime, compile it and invoke...

Comment: `throw new StackOverflowError()` - Or, too many nested method calls.

Comment: No code, no stacktrace, no answers

Comment: is looping allowed?

Comment: Looping is allowed

Comment: Seems like a valid question to me

Comment: It would be a valid question if the OP showed any evidence of having done ANY research or experimentation at all.

Comment: That's not a requirement on SO, or... even in life?  And the OP says he doesn't have any ideas... this one is admittedly tricky.  I like having to think, once is a while, so I appreciated the question.

Comment: @JimGarrison perhaps we should close SO. Because all questions could be solved through research and experimentation...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:**

The answer is incorrect, because it is one type of recursion. It is called indirect recursion https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)#Indirect_recursion.

<del>I think the simplest way to do this without recursion is the following:</del>

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

interface Handler {
    void handle(Chain chain);
}

interface Chain {
    void process();
}

class FirstHandler implements Handler {
    @Override
    public void handle(Chain chain) {
        System.out.println("first handler");
        chain.process();
    }
}

class SecondHandler implements Handler {
    @Override
    public void handle(Chain chain) {
        System.out.println("second handler");
        chain.process();
    }
}

class Runner implements Chain {
    private List<Handler> handlers;
    private int size = 5000; // change this parameter to avoid stackoverflowerror
    private int n = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runner runner = new Runner();
        runner.setHandlers();
        runner.process();
    }

    private void setHandlers() {
        handlers = new LinkedList<>();
        int i = 0;
        while (i < size) {
            // there can be different implementations of handler interface
            handlers.add(new FirstHandler());
            handlers.add(new SecondHandler());
            i += 2;
        }
    }

    public void process() {
        if (n < size) {
            Handler handler = handlers.get(n++);
            handler.handle(this);
        }
    }
}
```

At first glance this example looks a little crazy, but it's not as unrealistic as it seems.

The main idea of this approach is the **chain of responsibility** pattern. You can reproduce this exception in real life by implementing chain of responsibility pattern. For instance, you have some objects and every object after doing some logic call the next object in chain and pass the results of his job to the next one.

You can see this in java filter ([javax.servlet.Filter](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html)). 
I don't know detailed mechanism of working this class, but it calls the next filter in chain using doFilter method and after all filters/servlets processing request, it continue working in the same method below doFilter.

In other words it intercepts request/response before servlets and before sending response to a client.It is dangerous piece of code because all called methods are in the same stack at the same thread. Thus, **it may initiate stackoverflow exception if the chain is too big or you call doFilter method on deep level that also provide the same situation. Perhaps, during debugging you might see chain of calls
 in one thread** and it potentially can be the cause of stackoverflowerror.

Also you can take chain of responsibility pattern example from links below and add **collection of elements** instead of several and you also will get stackoverflowerror.

Links with the pattern:

https://www.journaldev.com/1617/chain-of-responsibility-design-pattern-in-java 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern

I hope it was helpful for you.

Comment: I like it. But a little bit complex explanation.

Comment: Good example, but it has recursion base, though it is covered by "chain of responsibility" pattern. We get SOE due to subsequent call of `Runner.process()` on each stack step, as we pass `this` for every next step: `handler.handle(this)`.

Answer (score 4):

Java stores primitive types on the stack. Objects created in local scope are allocated on the heap, with the reference to them on the stack.

You can overflow the stack without recursion by allocating too many primitive types in method scope. With normal stack size settings, you would have to allocate an excessive number of variables to overflow.

Comment: While SO doesn't require an explanation for how you vote, I would appreciate hearing the reason for the downvote.

Comment: Just something like
void method() {
long filed0 = 0;
long field1 = 1;
...
long field100500 = 100500;
}
???

Comment: Yes. Lots and lots of method-scoped variables. Without making the stack smaller, you'd probably want to write a little code generator or use a text editor macro to create enough variables.

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/65281/stack-and-heap-memory-in-java

Comment: I can't try this right now, but I suspect you'd hit a method-size limit in the compiler before you could overflow the default stack.  It appears the default stack in the Hotspot JVM is 1MB, so it would require about 131000 `long` or `double` variables.

Comment: I mean, you could also make like a million methods, `f0()`, `f1()`... `f1000000()`, and have one call the next one.  Technically this wouldn't be recursion since no method repeats.

Comment: @EricJ. And he would have to do it in such a way that all those variables aren't eliminated by the liveliness analysis and dead-code elimination during the optimization of the control flow graph. If generate anything, then rather a million of methods...

Comment: So... I can only throw this exception manually or generate very big java class like f0(), f1(), ..., f100000000(). This task is part of my career development program. If I will find a "normal" solution I will share it.

Comment: @JimGarrison Hotspot JVM isn't the only game in town. Java Embedded runs on systems with as little as 128KB RAM. Sure, you may run into restrictions on code size for a specific platform but I'm pretty sure you can declare (and use, so not optimized away) enough locals to blow an embedded stack.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the implementation of [Eric J.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/141172/eric-j) idea of generating excessive number of local variables using javassist library:

```
class SoeNonRecursive {
    static final String generatedMethodName = "holderForVariablesMethod";

    @SneakyThrows
    Class<?> createClassWithLotsOfLocalVars(String generatedClassName, final int numberOfLocalVarsToGenerate) {
        ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
        CtClass generatedClass = pool.makeClass(generatedClassName);
        CtMethod generatedMethod = CtNewMethod.make(getMethodBody(numberOfLocalVarsToGenerate), generatedClass);
        generatedClass.addMethod(generatedMethod);
        return generatedClass.toClass();
    }

    private String getMethodBody(final int numberOfLocalVarsToGenerate) {
        StringBuilder methodBody = new StringBuilder("public static long ")
                .append(generatedMethodName).append("() {")
                .append(System.lineSeparator());
        StringBuilder antiDeadCodeEliminationString = new StringBuilder("long result = i0");
        long i = 0;
        while (i < numberOfLocalVarsToGenerate) {
            methodBody.append("  long i").append(i)
                      .append(" = ").append(i).append(";")
                      .append(System.lineSeparator());
            antiDeadCodeEliminationString.append("+").append("i").append(i);
            i++;
        }
        antiDeadCodeEliminationString.append(";");
        methodBody.append("  ").append(antiDeadCodeEliminationString)
                  .append(System.lineSeparator())
                  .append("  return result;")
                  .append(System.lineSeparator())
                  .append("}");
        return methodBody.toString();
    }
}
```

and tests:

```
class SoeNonRecursiveTest {
    private final SoeNonRecursive soeNonRecursive = new SoeNonRecursive();
    //Should be different for every case, or once generated class become
    //"frozen" for javassist: http://www.javassist.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#read
    private String generatedClassName;

    @Test
    void stackOverflowWithoutRecursion() {
        generatedClassName = "Soe1";
        final int numberOfLocalVarsToGenerate = 6000;
        assertThrows(StackOverflowError.class, () -> soeNonRecursive
                .createClassWithLotsOfLocalVars(generatedClassName, numberOfLocalVarsToGenerate));
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    @Test
    void methodGeneratedCorrectly() {
        generatedClassName = "Soe2";
        final int numberOfLocalVarsToGenerate = 6;
        Class<?> generated = soeNonRecursive.createClassWithLotsOfLocalVars(generatedClassName, numberOfLocalVarsToGenerate);
        //Arithmetic progression
        long expected = Math.round((numberOfLocalVarsToGenerate - 1.0)/2 * numberOfLocalVarsToGenerate);
        long actual = (long) generated.getDeclaredMethod(generatedMethodName).invoke(generated);
        assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the question is very interesting, I have tried to simplify the answer of *hide* :

```
public class Stackoverflow {

    static class Handler {
        void handle(Chain chain){
            chain.process();
            System.out.println("yeah");
        }
    }

    static class Chain {

        private List<Handler> handlers = new ArrayList<>();
        private int           n        = 0;

        private void setHandlers(int count) {
            int i = 0;
            while (i++ < count) {
                handlers.add(new Handler());
            }
        }

        public void process() {
            if (n < handlers.size()) {
                Handler handler = handlers.get(n++);
                handler.handle(this);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Chain chain = new Chain();
        chain.setHandlers(10000);
        chain.process();
    }
}
```

It's important to note that if stackoverflow occurs, the string "yeah" will never be output.

Answer (score 1):

Of course we can do it :) . No recursion at all!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    throw new StackOverflowError();
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Looking at this answer below, not sure if this works for Java, but sounds like you can declare an array of pointers?  Might be able to achieve Eric J's idea without requiring a generator.

[Is it on the Stack or Heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056444/is-it-on-the-stack-or-heap)

```
int* x[LARGENUMBER];   // The addresses are held on the stack
int i;        // On the stack
for(i = 0; i < LARGENUMBER; ++i)
   x[i] = malloc(sizeof(int)*10);  // Allocates memory on the heap
```

Comment: That's `C`. I would really like to see how you would get a nice stack trace of a `StackOverflowError` out of that ;) And for some reason I had "alloca" in the back of my mind, but I don't see it in your code...

Comment: There is no static arrays in Java